# Python: two list iteration inside for loop for index

Tags: python, numpy

I have two lists: `list_1 = [0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0]` and `list_2 = [1,2,2,4,4,6,7,8,8,10]` that have the same number of elements. I am trying to loop through these lists to use in 4 separate values that will be part of a function.

I have so far:

```
list_1 = [0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0]
list_2 = [1,2,2,4,4,6,7,8,8,10]
for i,x in enumerate(list_1):
    var_list_1_1 = x
    var_list_1_2 = [z for y,z in enumerate(list_1) if y != i]
    var_list_2_1 = list_2[i]
    var_list_2_2 = [z for y,z in enumerate(list_2) if y != i]

    print("{}\n{}\n{}\n{}".format(var_list_1_1,var_list_1_2, var_list_2_1,var_list_2_2))
```

This prints correctly, but I am not sure if this is the best way. I will be using this with about one to two thousand rows of data and am unsure if this will potentially be an issue. I am using numpy and pandas as other libraries within this project, so solutions with these would work as well. Thanks for any insight you may have.

Edit:
I would like for each loop to produce something similar to below. It is the item, and then the list without that item in it. Both lists must be the same indexes of items. I am making a train/test feature set/array and a train/test target array for scikit learn if that helps. I just want to iterate through training the entire set and testing a single value.

```
var_list_1_1 = 0
var_list_1_2 = [1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0]
var_list_2_1 = 1
var_list_2_2 = [2,2,4,4,6,7,8,8,10]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it seems more readable:

```
for i in xrange(len(list_1)-1):
    l1 = list_1[:]
    l2 = list_2[:]
    var_list_1_1 = l1.pop(i)
    var_list_1_2 = l1
    var_list_2_1 = l2.pop(i)
    var_list_2_2 = l2
```

Comment: this works well for the stated lists, but my lists are in fact numpy arrays which don't have the pop feature :/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` in python and `array.T` method in numpy to crate a new array of the columns :

```
>>> list_1 = [0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0]
>>> list_2 = [1,2,2,4,4,6,7,8,8,10]
>>> for i,j in zip(list_1,list_2):
...     #do stuff
... 
>>>
```

Or :

```
>>> list_1 = np.array([0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0])
>>> list_2 = np.array([1,2,2,4,4,6,7,8,8,10])
>>> for i,j in np.array((list_1,list_2)).T:
...     #do stuff
... 
>>> 

>>> np.array((list_1,list_2)).T
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 1,  2],
       [ 0,  2],
       [ 0,  4],
       [ 1,  4],
       [ 1,  6],
       [ 0,  7],
       [ 1,  8],
       [ 1,  8],
       [ 0, 10]])
```

Comment: in these, wouldn't I still need to define the remaining list through either creating a new numpy array or list comprehension with the values? This would make it easier to link the two lists together, but from there how would I take item with index i from both lists and then take the remaining portions of the list as new separate variables?

Answer (score 1):

Or you can work with `List comprehensions` and reduce your code by one line, e.g. :

```
>>>[val for z in [(list_1[i], list_2[i]) for i in range(len(list_1)) ] for val in z]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 4, 1, 4, 1, 6, 0, 7, 1, 8, 1, 8, 0, 10]
```

Comment: "Look at all the `i`s"!